# Get Column Names of Values that are not NaN as new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have the dataframe below and I want another column that displays the column names of the values that are not NaN.
Like this:

```
New Column
y32
y9
y11
y9
```

and so on.

```
          y9        y2       y11       y32
1        NaN       NaN       NaN  0.201229
2   0.053303       NaN       NaN       NaN
4        NaN       NaN  0.442415       NaN
6   0.000529       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

I tried to do it with for loops but couldn't quite get there.
Help is very appreciated.

Comment: You should include the code that you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `idxmax` with `skipna=True` and apply it to each row:

```
def f(r):
     return r.idxmax(skipna=True)

df['New Column'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Or a one-liner:

```
df['New Column'] = df.apply(lambda r: r.idxmax(skipna=True), axis=1)
```

UPD:

A better way would be to use `Series.first_valid_index()`:

```
df['New Column'] = df.apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index, axis=1)
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you kind sir! And next time I will include my code my bad.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple approaches without using `pandas.DataFrame.apply`:

1. Using [`pandas.DataFrame.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) with `axis = 1` (columns)

```
>>> df["New Column"] = df.idxmax(1)
```

2. Using [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html)

```
>>> df["New Column"] = df.columns[np.where(df.notna())[1]]
```

In both cases the resulting dataframe is:

```
         y9  y2       y11       y32 New Column
1       NaN NaN       NaN  0.201229        y32
2  0.053303 NaN       NaN       NaN         y9
4       NaN NaN  0.442415       NaN        y11
6  0.000529 NaN       NaN       NaN         y9
```

Comment: Didn't think about using idxmax on axis. I like this solution more